# Why is magnetic field parallel to the surface of a conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, boundary-conditions

On Jackson- Classical Electrodynamics it is said that, for a perfect conductor the magnetic field is always parallel to the surface, that is

$$\mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf {n}=0$$

I do not understand how this relation is deduced from interface conditions present [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_conditions_for_electromagnetic_fields) . In particular, how can one show that the magnetic field inside the conductor is zero? (From there, unsing the interface condition for B, one could deduce the parallelism of B).

Comment: I don't have my copy of Jackson handy at the moment but, according to the [Perfect conductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_conductor) article at Wikipedia, $\mathbf{B}$ is *constant* in a perfect conductor and *zero* in a superconductor.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to change the magnetic field going into a perfect conductor, induction (via Lenz’s law) will act perfectly to prevent that.

We generally assume these unobtanium-based “perfect” conductors start with zero embedded field, so they’ll always have zero embedded field.

Answer (score 1):

Because a normal component would imply a monopole source which is not there. Apply Gauss Law and you get a source.